# Android Studio 2.2 adds @+id to all my textArea and imageView ids causing errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I am brand new to Android development.  Android Studio 2.2 won't allow me to delete the "@+id/" from the id in the properties menu.  However, when I try to add Java code or build the project, those @+id/ s cause build errors.

Please forgive my ignorance.  My class's textbook is for Android Studio 1.5 and it's hard to search for "@" and "+".

[image: Screenshot of @+id in properties window]
[image]

Comment: clean and build project

Comment: Click the "Text" Tab. Edit the XML

Comment: Why should I have to manually edit the XML?  This is stupid.  If I could type in a valid id in the Properties window there would be no need for me to clean up after Android Studio's mess.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Text mode and delete it from there rather than using the Design mode in this kind of cases.

Comment: Are you telling me that every time I give a Widget an id, I will have to manually delete "@+id" from the markup for that element??

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on how you added the element. In Text mode, you can add an element without "@+id" although when using Design mode, an id is automatically generated for every element you add.

Also I tried what you did, I dragged an element using Design mode into the XML, and by looking at the properties, the properties textfield doesn't contain "@+id" in this case you should just delete "@+id/" from the textfield and leave the rightful id name e.g. "progressBar"

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address my problem.  However, if I was able to simply edit the ID property to a valid name I wouldn't have posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That doesn't happen on my android studio. However, you should be able to edit it in Text mode so you can make the necessary changes. in Text mode though the element should be built up like this "android:id="@+id/textview"

Comment: I finally figured out what I was doing wrong.

For some reason, if I press "Enter" after entering the id name, it adds "@+id/" to the id name.  However, if I type in the proper name, such as txtInfo, and click outside the properties window, it doesn't add this pesky "@+id/" to the id.  

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Not sure either why it does that. Perhaps some bug from the new Android Studio version. Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what I was doing "wrong."

For some reason, if I press "Enter" after entering the id name, it adds "@+id/" to the id name, causing errors in both the Java code and the XML.  However, if I type in the proper name, such as txtInfo, and click outside the properties window, it doesn't add this pesky "@+id/" to the id name.

No idea why.